# Disable Network Set

Tags: connection

I am changing to a new network with Sky but my Tor keeps switching it off and says `Disable Network set`.

I have upgraded to Sky Q and have a new hub which means a new network.

Comment: I must clarify.  Is there a way around the Tor Disable Network problem by using Bridges?

Comment: Can you post more details about how you've configured Tor and if you're in a country that censors Tor? Has Tor worked previously, and what exactly did you change? Also can you post the relevant log lines?

Comment: I configured it fine.  Tor is working fine, no problem, this has nothing to do with the configuration.  It was working fine.  I got a new hub from my provider for Sky Q and put the details to connect into the WIFI on my Kindle Fire and connected, following the instructions to add the network.  
 The Web came on and I then opened Tor to connect to the Internet.  The message said Disable Network Setup.  Tor would not connect.  I tried using Bridges to connect and was sent a code.  I tried 4 times, gave up.  I connected to the old hub instead.  That works fine.  No Tor isn't censored.

Comment: What are log lines?

Comment: I don't understand why its not obvious what happened.  I changed from one hub to a new one.  The web information was put in and it connected.  Tor switches it off immediately I go to the net via Tor.  The message is Disable Network Setup.  I returned to old hub, everything works.  I need to be able to use the new hub on my device with Tor as I have never had a problem before.  We need the new hub for Sky Q.  It won't work otherwise and we can't upgrade without it.  It's got nothing to do with my configuration.  Tor connects to other networks all the time away from home.

Comment: "Tor is working fine, no problem" -> I assume you mean the Tor Browser here, not Tor the network client or some kind of transparent proxy? "Got a new hub from my provider for Sky Q" -> provider means ISP? And what's a Sky Q, a modem/router? "The message said Disable Network Setup" -> What message? Was it in a pop-up? Was there anything else in the message, or was it only those 3 words? "Tor switches it off immediately I go to the net via Tor" -> Tor switches what off? Do you just mean it can't connect?

Comment: "put the details to connect into the WIFI on my Kindle Fire and connected" -> Are you using Tor Browser on Android, or Orfox? Have you tried the Tor Browser on a computer?

Comment: My Tor on my Kindle is working fine.  I don't have anything else.  My laptop has not worked for years and sorry but we can't all afford new computers.  It works fine on my tablet.  No. Sky is my broadband and internet and WIFI provider in U.K.

Comment: No Tor on tablet working fine. Sky Q is a satellite TV box. It comes with a router, what we call a hub.  For the broadband and WI-Fi internet and TV.   Sky is a cable and satellite company.  We did an upgrade.  Had to put new information on to tablet for connecting.  Tor shut down the connection and would not connect.  Not a pop up.  Tor normally starts and confirm connection to Tor Network.  Instead Disable Network Setup.  Yes, nothing else.  Tor can't connect new router.  Back old router.  Works fine.

Comment: I don't have a laptop.  I do everything on my tablet.  Never had any problems until the new router connection which it won't accept.

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't connect.  How do I get around this to connect?  Tablet is Android.  I also have Orfox.  I have never had trouble connection before when I have had a new router or gone on holiday.  I don't know why it has defaulted now to Disable Network Setup.  Thanks.